# Removing controller name and function namein URL in Codeigniter CMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, content-management-system, uri

I am building a cms in codeigniter and i want to remove controller name and function name form the url and just print the alias.
I will be having two controllers one for static pages and other for blog posts with categories.
Please help, Suggestions reagrding modification of two controllers are also welcome.

Comment: use codeigniter config routes file http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I looked into that and was not able to make it function according to my need. 
Can anybody explain in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the default 404 controller in `application/config/routes.php`.

`$route['404_override'] = 'content';`

Any request that can't be mapped to a controller will be passed to the `application/controllers/content.php` controller

Your `Content` controller, or whatever you decide to call it, will parse the uri [`$this->uri->segment(1)`] and check for a matching reference in your CMS database.

If there is no match in the database, then you can look for a static view in the views folder and load it.

```
if(is_file(FCPATH.'views/'.$this->uri->segment(1).'.php')) {
    $this->load->view($controller,$this->data);
}
```

If no static view is found, and there is no matching content in the db, call the `show_404()` function.

Using this method, you will keep the default CI functionality of uri mapping, so at any time, you can add controllers as you normally would and the app will perform like a vanilla CI install.